# SSL Handshake error in Python (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to get a response using python requests. However I'm facing SSL Handshake error. I tried many solutions posted here, but nothing seems to work. Please help. Thanks in advance

This is the code:

```
import requests
url = "https://androidappsapk.co/download/com.facebook.katana"
requests.get(url, verify = False)
```

This is the error that I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 382, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

P.S. - I am using Python 2.7.11

Comment: The server seems to have [problems](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=androidappsapk.co&s=104.18.56.222) with OpenSSL 0.98 clients. What OpenSSL version do you use?

Comment: I'm using OpenSSL version 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated OpenSSL to the latest version and it's working fine now :)